# Команда subprocess вызывает ошибку

Tags: python, cmd

Здравствуйте.

Суть такова, есть команда для включения CGI в IIS:

> Start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-CGI

([источник](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753077(v=ws.10).aspx))

Мне ее нужно выполнить в python-скрипте, мой код:

```
subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=LOG_FILE)
```

При исполнении скрипта (под админом) выскакивает окно

> Не удалось выполнить операцию, ошибка 0x8007000B, Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат

при этом, если просто запустить команду - она срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Я правильное понимаю, что `Start` это исполняемый файл? Если, да тогда попробуйте указать полный путь к нему.

---

Вы уверены что хотите вызывать команду через `subprocess.call`? Если это скрипт, а не сервис со сложной логикой, верояино, в данном случае, будет проще использовать `os.system(command)`.